# Phoenix bloodline and Catching on Fire

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, damage, magic, healing

How does the healing from the [phoenix bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/phoenix-sorcerer-bloodline/) work with spells and effects that cause targets to be on fire? Spells such as [Touch of Combustion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/touch-of-combustion) or [Alchemist's Inferno Fireball Trick](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/magic-trick-2/)? The fireball trick has a fair argument that the fire it produces are magic as they use the spell save DC.

I have seen various discussions on reddit and other posts that claim by raw it works! Or that it doesn't work at all. I have not seen anything conclusive, or a good argument for either side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Catching on Fire is an Environmental effect; Phoenix Blood Arcana does not apply*

*usually, see below

The rules for [Catching on Fire](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules/#Catching_on_Fire) are in the Environmental Rules section and an exception to the normal rules that instantaneous fire spells do not light fires nor deal continuing damage. If a spell references adding that *condition* (and does not have a duration), then the Catching on Fire is not part of the "damage the spell would normally deal".

There are exceptions; for instance, Touch of Combustion references *also* dealing 1d4 "damage" (with a Reflex Saving throw) to any creatures adjacent to ones on fire. This is damage the *spell* does in addition to the environmental effect of being caught on fire. The 1d4 would be healing (while the poor person on fire would still take 1d6 damage from the very real fire).

Alchemist Inferno is *not* an exception because it is still inflicting the *environmental rules* for catching something on fire; it just increases the DC because honestly DC 15 is a joke by the time the Magic Trick is available.

Comment: My co-gms and I discussed how we would even go about letting it work as the typical catching on fire does not have a duration. We came to the conclusion that it would be best to just say it doesnt work. Setting an arbitrary duration makes low level spells like touch of combustion really good, and trying to work out a mechanic for scaling duration is a lot of effort. TL;DR - Not worth it.

Comment: Too small an edit: Compustion should be Combustion, second paragraph.

Comment: I said what I said, CGCampbell =P JK, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As Ifusaso correctly pointed out, it's important to check whether catching fire references the environmental rules or is its own (spell) effect.

[Alchemist's Fire](https://www.aonprd.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Alchemist%27s%20fire) as an additional material component for [Fireball](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Fireball) is a great example of that difference, because it depends on how you use it:

- Using it with the [Alchemist's Inferno Magic Trick](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/magic-trick-2/#Fireball_Tricks) does **not** work with Phoenix bloodline arcana.
- Using it as an [Alchemical Power Component](https://www.aonprd.com/AlchemicalReagents.aspx) **does** in fact work with the Phoenix bloodline arcana.

In general, alchemical power components enhance a spell's effect and usually don't reference the environmental rules, so using these is preferable for a Phoenix Sorcerer. It doesn't even require a feat (Magic Trick), nor 9 ranks in two skills to use.